# MVC 5 RadioButtonFor enum, the default enum value zero is always selected?

Tags: radio-button, html-helper, asp.net-mvc-5.2

Say I have an enum:

```
public enum OrderStatusType
{
    Waiting = 0,
    Pending,
    Picked,
    Shipped,        
}
```

I generated the radio button list as follows.

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Status, OrderStatusType.Shipped, new {@checked = true})
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Status, OrderStatusType.Waiting)
```

But the Waiting is always selected.  The output HTML is as below:

```
input type="radio" value="Shipped" name="Status" id="Status" checked="True"
input type="radio" value="Waiting" name="Status" id="Status" checked="checked"
```

Why is a "checked" attribute automatically added by MVC framework? 
Thanks.

The model:

```
public class OrderViewModel
{
    public OrderStatusType Status { get; set; }
}
```

The view:

```
@using WebApplication17.Controllers
@model WebApplication17.Models.OrderViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}


@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Status, OrderStatusType.Picked)
<span>@OrderStatusType.Picked</span>

@Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>m.Status, OrderStatusType.Pending)
<span>@OrderStatusType.Pending</span>

@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Status, OrderStatusType.Shipped, new {@checked = true})
<span>@OrderStatusType.Shipped</span>

@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Status, OrderStatusType.Waiting)
<span>@OrderStatusType.Waiting</span>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Its selected because the value of your property `Status` is `OrderStausType.Waiting` (that's how binding works!).

Remove `new {@checked = true}` from the `@Html.RadioButtonFor()` method and in your controller, set the value of `Status` to `OrderStausType.Shipped` before you pass it to the view.

Note also you should use a `<label>` element rather that a `<span>` to associate the label with the radio button

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Status, OrderStausType.Picked, new {id = OrderStausType.Picked)
<label for=@OrderStausType.Picked>@OrderStausType.Picked</label>
```